# GRUB not showing up after tinkering partition

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I had dual-boot ubuntu 16 and windows 10 and both were working fine, until one day when I was tinkering with my partition in windows and grub started showing some error. But I had not touched the partition where ubuntu is installed. I tried following some tutorials on internet and now grub is not showing up. I am able to login to windows normally.

Legacy mode - enabled
Secure Boot - disabled
Fast Boot - Off

I tried repairing grub with boot-repair. Here is the log - http://paste2.org/eBjts2NY

Comment: Your boot-info-summary doesn't show any Ubuntu-related partitions, only NTFS-partitions. If Ubuntu has been installed on an external HDD, this drive should be connected at boot-time. Otherwise you may have reformatted your Ubuntu-partitions with NTFS-file-format. That would mean you have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: no, it was on internal disk only on the same partition where windows is installed on C drive.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way to install Ubuntu on the same partition as Windows is via [WUBI,](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) which is no longer supported and, AFAIK, does not work with an EFI-mode boot, which your system is clearly using. Thus, if you used WUBI, you were playing with something *very* obscure and bleeding-edge on your particular system, and your best bet at getting help is to consult whatever instructions you followed.

Also, you haven't clearly described the symptoms of your boot failure. Are you not seeing a GRUB menu appear? Does GRUB appear but selecting Ubuntu in the menu causes some failure? If so, what error messages or other symptoms are you seeing?

One thing I note in your Boot Repair output is that your firmware's boot order is set to boot Windows first:

```
=================== efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,2001,2002,2004
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,308fb967-7769-427d-a80b-c6c93749aef4,0x145800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,308fb967-7769-427d-a80b-c6c93749aef4,0x145800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0002* Notebook Hard Drive - HGST HTS541010A9E680    BBS(HD,Notebook Hard Drive - HGST HTS541010A9E680,0x500)................-.E.......E.A.E...................................&4........A.........................
Boot0003* USB Hard Drive - KingstonDataTraveler 2.0 BBS(7,USB Hard Drive - KingstonDataTraveler 2.0,0x500)...................................................................;........A.....................
Boot0004* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - KingstonDataTraveler 2.0  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x71,0x800,0xef3800)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
```

Note the `BootOrder` line, which specifies that `Boot0001` (`Windows Boot Manager`) is first in the list. A couple of possibilities occur to me:

- If your boot process passed through the Windows boot manager, then this is correct, and the solution lies in fixing the Windows boot manager configuration.
- If the boot process should have passed through GRUB, then you need to adjust the `BootOrder` variable. You can do this with `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu (e.g., `sudo efibootmgr -o 0,1,2001,2002,2004`, which will reverse the order of the `Boot0001` and `Boot0000` options) or using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows, which can do the same thing via a GUI tool.

*DO NOT* try one of these solutions randomly! It's *critical* that you understand what your boot process had been before you attempt a repair, since picking the wrong option is likely to make matters worse.

All of this, of course, is predicated on the assumption that you're correct in assuming that you had a WUBI-style installation. If not, then chances are mook765 is correct and you've accidentally wiped out the Ubuntu installation. (Alternatively, it might be on a second physical disk -- maybe its cable has come loose or the disk itself has died.) As I said, AFAIK WUBI doesn't work on EFI-mode installations -- full stop. Maybe I'm wrong about that, or maybe there's something else (a fork of WUBI or some other project with similar goals) of which I'm unaware. In any event, I think you need to clarify, at least to yourself, how you installed Ubuntu before you proceed any further.